# Using ContentObserver to monitor a variable change

Tags: android, string, uri, contentobserver

Is it possible to use a `ContentObserver` to monitor variable changes (e.g. String) by constructing a Uri and passing it as an argument when registering? If yes, can you provide a functional example?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I used Uri uri=Uri.parse(myString) but I got "Invalid Uri used for observer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work by doing Uri.parse on an arbitrary string value.

I don't think it will work at all. What's the use case? It suggests that something outside of your control is modifying a variable. How can this happen?

Comment: I wanted to monitor running tasks changes using the ActivityManager and I thought I could use a ContentObserver to notify me when a change occurs, avoiding periodic polling. But I had to stick to looping anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with string value,

It works with me. I have used `Uri.parse` like below:

```
contentResolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://com.example.provider/notification"), null)
```